# Problem configuring proxy with authentication in selenium chromedriver Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, proxy, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I have a Java program in which I need selenium webdriver to connect to a URL through a proxy with authentication but something is wrong with the configuration.

I can access the URL through the proxy in a separate test program, but not with selenium and chromedriver.

I'm following the guide they have but it's for python: https://www.zenrows.com/docs/selenium

This is my code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
        
String zenRowsApiKey = "myAPIkey";
String proxyHost = "proxy.zenrows.com";
int proxyPort = 8001;

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

String proxyUrl = "http://" + zenRowsApiKey + ":premium_proxy=true@" + proxyHost + ":" + proxyPort;
options.addArguments("--proxy-server=" + proxyUrl);
options.addArguments("--headless");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

driver.get("http://ident.me/");

WebElement bodyElement = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
String response = bodyElement.getText();
System.out.println(response);
```

By executing this code, I always access through my IP and not through the proxy.

In the guide they say the following: Since Chrome doesn't support authenticated proxies, you'll need selenium-wire.
But, in Java, what would be the corresponding for that?

**UPDATE**

I have also tried with WebDriverManager following this guide:
https://www.zenrows.com/blog/selenium-proxy-java

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

String proxyAddress = "proxy.zenrows.com";
int proxyPort = 8001;
String proxyUsername = "myAPIkey";
String proxyPassword = "";

Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy(proxyAddress + ":" + proxyPort);
proxy.setSslProxy(proxyAddress + ":" + proxyPort);

String proxyAuth = proxyUsername + ":" + proxyPassword;
proxy.setProxyType(Proxy.ProxyType.MANUAL);
// Here I've tried with and without "http://" + before the proxyAuth
proxy.setHttpProxy("http://" + proxyAuth + "@" + proxyAddress + ":" + proxyPort);
proxy.setSslProxy("http://" + proxyAuth + "@" + proxyAddress + ":" + proxyPort);

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setProxy(proxy);
options.addArguments("--headless");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

driver.get("http://ident.me/");

WebElement bodyElement = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
String response = bodyElement.getText();
System.out.println(response);
```

But the result is the same, I access the URL from my IP address and not through the proxy.

All versions are compatible with each other:

- selenium: 4.18.1
- webdrivermanager: 5.6.4
- Chrome browser: 121.0.6167.185